# Providing odom to move_base through a map->odom tf

Tags: navigation, mapping, gmapping, move-arm, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm providing odometry to move_base through a map->odom tf provided by hector_mapping.

This means that my odom topic is empty, which I think is the cause of a host of warnings, such as:

```
[ WARN] [1368064440.957099892, 700.300000000]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 700.3000, global_pose stamp: 700.0000, tolerance: 0.3000

[ WARN] [1368064440.957199828, 700.300000000]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration
```

I have managed to make move_base ignore the lack of odom messages by going to  costmap_2d_ros.cpp of the costmap_2d package and doing this (warning: this is a bad hack!):

```
    // check global_pose timeout
if (current_time.toSec() - global_pose.stamp_.toSec() > transform_tolerance_) {
  ROS_WARN_THROTTLE(1.0, "Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: %.4f, global_pose stamp: %.4f, tolerance: %.4f",
      current_time.toSec() ,global_pose.stamp_.toSec() ,transform_tolerance_);
  return true;
//  return false;
}
```

**My question: is this a dangerous workaround? Is there a better way to tell move_base to ignore the odom topic?**

Thank you in advance,

**EDIT**

Sometimes, the two times are **very** different, which leads me to think that they might be in different time epochs:

```
Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 1368081077.4015, global_pose stamp: 136.4000, tolerance: 0.3000
```

When this happens, the quick hack described above doesn't help..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62422/providing-odom-to-move_base-through-a-map-%3Eodom-tf/) by [Ernest](https://answers.ros.org/users/4002/ernest/) on ROS Answers with karma: 341 on 2013-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not a good idea. If your timing is off, you need to fix that other than try to make the warning go away. See my answer to your [other question](http://answers.ros.org/question/62435/tf-frames-in-different-time-epoch-from-ros-time/) about the different time epochs.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ernest](https://answers.ros.org/users/4002/ernest/) on 2013-05-09**:
Thanks. Your answer to the question for the different time epochs solved the second scenario (Current time: 1368081077.4015, global_pose stamp: 136.4000)
for the first scenario (Current time: 700.3000, global_pose stamp: 700.0000) I made transform_tolerance param higher and that fixed the problem.